# I have a scratched CD that can be played but cannot be copied

Tags: windows-7

I have a badly scratched CD whose content cannot be copied to the hard disk. My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Windows can’t copy the 750 MB video file. It can be played by VLC Media Player, but when I try to copy it, it copies to 6% and then just stops. How I can copy my file?

Comment: It may be copy-protected. Google the title with 'copy protection' & see what you find.

Comment: LMGTFU - First result: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/recover-photo-and-data-from-scratched-or-damaged-cd/

Comment: Carefully fill the scratch with clear nail polish, let dry, it should rip now.

Comment: If you’re fine with errors in the video stream, you could try a specialized data recovery program that just skips areas it can’t read.

Answer (score 4):

If you can play it on VLC - you can use it to dump out the contents. It's slightly well hidden, but go to media, then convert/save.

[image]

You need to pick the file with this menu *or* use the disk option if it's a DVD (I think).

Click on convert/save.

[image]

Here I picked dump raw input. This is *significantly* faster, but with either this or convert, there's no obvious sign it's done. Just check back in a bit. It's a good idea to *explicitly include* the file extension in the target because VLC won't add that for you. Convert will transcode the file and for a "quick" backup, isn't really needed. Unlike what I did, pick another drive.

Since VLC is literally reading and dumping the video, you should get a copy you can use elsewhere assuming VLC can read it.

Answer (score 1):

If the top of the CD is scratched, it’s done for. If not, the cheapest thing you can try is to get some plain white toothpaste and rub it on the underside of the CD from the center out towards the edge. Do this around the CD a few times until the CD is coated. Let it dry and rinse it off. If it is really badly scratched, try it a few times.

I’ve had success with this in the past. Alternatively, if they even still make them (it’s been 15 years since I tried) they used to sell CD repair kits that were a set of gears and spinning mild abrasive disks that would smooth the underside.

Comment: CD is not copy protected . It is scratched and have some spot. It can be played by vlc. after I have used tooth paste.  But unable to copy after 10- 20 %